# add on-scrolling effect to wordpress with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, onscroll

I am trying to implement this effect in wordpress:

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-CSS-Easing-Based-Scroll-Animations-circus-scroll-tween/

I followed the implementation guide but it is not animating.

I included the js files in `function.php`, like this:

```
<?php
function addScroll_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('js1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/circus-scroll-tween.min.js', array('jquery'), '',  false);
    wp_enqueue_script('js2.frame-carousel.min', get_template_directory_uri().'/main.min.js', array(), '0.1.0', false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addScroll_scripts' );
?>
```

I've worked on this problem for a day but I still don't know what's the problem. I almost forgot to say that I put the js files directly in my theme folder.

Comment: i find the way to animate my webpage elements on scroll with scrollme.js, here is the site: http://scrollme.nckprsn.com/#options. every thing work fine on chrome but it dosn't work on firefox and IE. i don't know what's the problem.